# Understanding use of new keyword inside Unslider.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  difficulty in understanding a syntax I found in a jQuery Plugin. Below is the syntax:

```
instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);
```

In the above line what `init` is of-course a function where `me` is = `$(this)` and `o` is an object literal, passed when calling the plugin. now in order to understand the above line, I went ahead and read a few articles which I am not sure are relevant.

i read a nice article here : [simple class instantiating](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) , but still my confusion persists .

If I translate the line I am having a difficulty with to plain English:

I would read it something like this:

*make instance a new instanse of unslider and than run the function init with the parameters (o,me).*

But if the above interpretation of mine is correct then,

```
instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);
```

should be re-written as

```
instance = new Unslider;
init(me, o);
```

So coming back to my question, what is:

```
instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);
```

doing?

P.S. I would appreciate also if you can point me to any resource that would give me a good understanding of such syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make instance a new instanse of unslider and than run the function
>   init with the parameters (o,me).

You're correct.

It could be also rewritten like the following code:

```
new Unslider().init(me, o);
```

Parenthesis are operators to group expression results. For example, you can also do something like this:

```js
var result = (1 + 2).toString();

alert(result);
```

That is, the value obtained of adding `1` and `2` is returned as a `number` and you can call `toString()` since this function is part of any object in JavaScript.

`(new Unslider)` is the same case: the value of the parenthesis is the object created from the `Unslider` prototype, so you can call instance members (i.e. functions, properties...) of the whole object.

Why they decided to use this syntax and not just `new Unslider().init(me, o)`, who knows. IMHO, I would use my option, because instantiating an object and just that doesn't require the parenthesis syntax...

### Additional note...

You should know that you won't be able to do so:

```
// This would be using the result of .init(me, o) as the 
// constructor function, and I'm very sure .init(me, o) won't
// return a function, so this would end in a run-time error
new Unslider.init(me, o);
```

In summary, `new` keyword should be used with functions, and when a function is used in a `new` expressions, the so-called function turns into a *constructor function*.

You might learn more about constructors and prototypes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth Answer , i'll go through it and accept , just gimme some time.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik No problem. The goal was explaining it ;) You're welcome